# Flowable runs on main thread even though subscribeOn() is called on another thread

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

The problem is that I am trying to get some data from the server, and I
**subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())**,

but whenever I try to print the current thread once I try to get data from the server I get the main Thread.

am I missing something?

First on here are some mock data

```
private static Map<String, User> SERVICE_DATA;

static {
    SERVICE_DATA = new LinkedHashMap<>(2);
    new User("1", "User1");
    new User("2", "User2");
}
```

here is onCreate Method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getUsers()
            .flatMap(Flowable::fromIterable)
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    // onNext
                    users -> {
                        //do something with the users list
                    },
                    // onError
                    throwable -> {

                    });
}
```

here is my main method to get the data

```
 private Flowable<List<User>> getUsers() {
    return getRemoteUsers().flatMap(users -> Flowable.fromIterable(users).toList().toFlowable());
}
```

get Remote data

```
private Flowable<List<User>> getRemoteUsers() {
    return Flowable
            .fromIterable(getMockData())
            .delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .toList()
            .toFlowable();
}
```

To be replaced with real data from the server.

```
private Collection<User> getMockData() {
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    Log.d("WTF", "currentThread id: " + t.getId() + " name: " + t.getName());

    return SERVICE_DATA.values();

}
```

Comment: `getRemoteUsers()` is not subscribed on `Schedulers.io()`.

Comment: I already tried but still same result 
getRemoteUsers().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

Comment: and I even added it to                 .fromIterable(getMockData())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

Comment: You mean `getMockData()` should run on background thread? Then you should use`Flowable.fromCallable()` and subscribe **that** on Schedulers.io, instead of `fromIterable` directly

Comment: thank you. it is working as expected.